# Value of type 'UICollectionView' has no member 'beginUpdates' - Swift 3 issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I was using NSFetchedResultsController for core data .

And on implementing controllerWillChangeContent() method.

```
        self.collectionView.beginUpdates()
```

shows error from Xcode 8 , swift 3 .

Any suggestion.

Comment: You can see [this answear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34694755/6282606).

Answer (score 26):

`beginUpdates` is from `UITableView`. `UICollectionView` has the `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` method.

I suggest reviewing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20554673/1226963) for information on using `NSFetchedResultsController` and `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I had used like this  
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath])
                }, completion: { (result) in
                    self.scrollToBottom(animated: true) //private method for scroll up.
                })
Thanks for help

Comment: thanks to @rmaddy for the explanation and link to that amazing QA !